# Custom sub menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom tab bars by following the post given below:

[How to create a Tab-like UI in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375350/how-to-create-a-tab-like-ui-in-android/11375768#11375768)

No I need to display a set on sub menu when the center tab (actually it is a button) is clicked. I need the sub menu to pop up like in this drawing (sub menu should be above my main layout):

[image]

I believe that this can be achieved by putting an additional layout above the custom tab bar in which a set of buttons can be placed one after another. But I am not sure which layout needs to be used and how I can get the same style in the drawing. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: this is my question too

Answer (score 1):

you're correct with just adding another layout above the button you want to open it, and then setting its visibility to gone until you want to animate in it.

a regular LinearLayout would work fine, and then adding 4 buttons to it would work as well, then you would want to make sure those buttons used the same styles as the built-in android menu buttons (or style it yourself) but check out some of the built in styles [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

example:

your activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  //all your other activity layout stuff goes here

  <!--add your new menu-->
  <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/my_menu_layout"
  android:visibility="gone"
  ... />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/menu_btn_1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.TextButton" //as example of built-in style
    ... />

    //more buttons

  </LinearLayout>
```

then in your activity class, assign an onClickListener to the button that will toggle the menu and animate the view in

```
//animation xml you make
Animation inFromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_in_bottom); 
mMenuLayout.startAnimation(inFromBottom);       
mMenuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

now your view will animate in and you can go about adding onClick listeners to the buttons

Comment: Thanks for the response. It will be great, if you can provide some code and elaborate your answer.